# What parameter to nth child should I use?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need to get 2,5,8 to customize.
How can I get get 2,5,8 in nth child?

```
  <div class="col">
           1<h3>aa</h3>
           2<p>bb</p>
           3<p>cc</p>
            
           4 <h3>aa</h3>
           5 <p>bb</p>
           6 <p>cc</p> 
          
           7 <h3>aa</h3>
           8 <p>bb</p>
           9 <p>cc</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use formulas with nth-child.

What you want is:

```
.col p:nth-child(3n+2){}
```

Comment: You are right, I was probably too hasty. Anyway, I've corrected it

Comment: No problem, you deserve it.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.col  p:nth-child(3n+2) {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <h3>aa</h3>
  <p>bb</p>
  <p>cc</p>
  <h3>aa</h3>
  <p>bb</p>
  <p>cc</p>
  <h3>aa</h3>
  <p>bb</p>
  <p>cc</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It works! can you please help me to understand about that

Comment: @ChiieCruz https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp read the documentation, and google some examples. Also Ruben was first too answer, but had a typo, fill free to accept his answer